# how to Rename ssis solution

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have one doubt in ssis
how to rename solution and folders using ssis solution

solution name : Test_First_V1
Foldername: Test_First_V1

inside folder again have Test_First_V1.dtproj

how will rename all from Test_First_V1 to 
 Test_First_V2

I Tried 
step1:open the solution and right click on solution rename
the Test_First_V1 to   Test_First_V2 and save it
after that I closed the solution

Step2: rename the folders from Test_First_V1 to   Test_First_V2 
Step 3: again open the solution this time getting warnning
one or more project in the solution were not loaded correctly
plase see the outputwindow for details

i have seen outputwindow no message there

can you please help me how to rename soution and solution related folders in ssis